# How do you create a unique key within a 2D array using React and JavaScript for a chessboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, chess

[image]I am new to building applications and coding, as a side project I am trying to make a chessboard with react and JavaScript. I am currently stuck trying to figure out a way to make a unique id key  inside the 2D for loop in the Chessboard component below:

Here is the code for the Tile component

```
import './Tile.css';

const WhiteTile = () =>
{
   return(
      <div className='TileWhite'></div>
   )
}

const AquaTile = () =>
{
   return(
      <div className='TileAqua'></div>
   )
}


const ENUM_OBJECT = 
{
   whiteTile: <WhiteTile/>,
   aquaTile: <AquaTile/>,
};

function Tile({tileType}) 
{
   return ENUM_OBJECT[tileType]
}

export default Tile;
```

this is the code for the Chessboard component

```
import React from 'react';  
import '../ChessBoard/Chessboard.css'
import Tile from './Tile';



function ChessBoard()
{  
    const xCoordinates = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "0"];


    const yCoordinates = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
    
    const coordinatesBoard = []; 

    const RenderCoordinates = () =>
    {

        for(let y = yCoordinates.length; y > 0; y--)
        {
            for(let x = 0; x < xCoordinates.length - 1; x++)
            {   
                if(x % 2 === 0)
                {
                    coordinatesBoard.push(<Tile tileType={"whiteTile"} key={''}></Tile>);
                }
                else
                {
                    coordinatesBoard.push(<Tile tileType={"aquaTile"} key={''}></Tile>);

                }
            }
        }
        return coordinatesBoard; 
    }


    return(<div className="App">
            {<RenderCoordinates/>}
            </div>)
    
}

export default ChessBoard;
```

I tried using a map function earlier

```
 const RenderTiles = () =>
    {
        const cBoard = coordinatesBoard.map((xyCoordinates, index) =>
        {
                if(index % 2)
                {
                    return(
                    <div className ="Tile1" key={index}>
                        {xyCoordinates}
                    </div>
                    )
                }
                else 
                {
                    return(
                    <div className ="Tile2" key={index}>
                        {xyCoordinates}
                    </div>
                    )
                }
        });

        return cBoard
    }
```

also looked into useState

```
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const increment = () => 
    {
    
        setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
```

Tried inserting counter in here but ran into an infinite loop(from the Chessboard function)

```
coordinatesBoard.push(<Tile tileType={"whiteTile"} key={counter + 1}></Tile>);
```

I was expecting the counter to increment every time a Tile was pushed on the Chessboard
pls help.

Comment: Are the keys meant to represent normal [chess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard#Board_notation)?

Comment: @Andy Not at the moment, just trying to implement a unique identifier, the board itself is not a checkered pattern at the moment, I was thinking that the unique key would get rid of the error in the console as well as help me get the checkered pattern down

Comment: The coordinates are the correct chess notation though, it is not visible just yet but I checked it before pushing the tiles

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do and how the result you got differs from your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a basic random string generator (not always guaranteed to be unique but it's pretty random)

```
function randomString() {
  const possibleChars = 'abcxyz123'
  const length = 10

  const randString = []

  for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
    const randomChar = possibleChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleChars.length)]
    randString.push(randomChar)
  }
  
  return randString.join('')
}

console.log(randomString()) // "3zb1baxbbyy"
```